# How to write multi line query in snowflake scripting in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
 create or replace procedure create_src_table() 
 returns table (name varchar, age number(10,0),dob date) 
 language sql as 
 $$ 
 declare  
 create_query varchar;
 res resultset; 
 begin   
 create_query := `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SRC_TEMP_TBL AS SELECT * FROM  
                   (WITH CTE_1 AS (SELECT * FROM "DB"."DW"."USER_TBL" WHERE name='rahul'),
                  CTE_2 AS (SELECT * FROM CTE_1 WHERE CAST(DOB AS DATE)<2000-05-01)
                  SELECT name,age,dob FROM CTE_2 limit 10)`;

res := (execute immediate : create_query);
return table(res);
end;
$$;

call create_src_table();
```

Could someone please help in how to write multiline sql query. I found few answers that indicate using backtick in javascript but not sure how to achieve it in sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-statement SQL should be wrapped inside `BEGIN ... END` block:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN 
                   statement1;
                   statement2; 
                   ...
                   END;';
```

Sample:
[image]

Comment: Thank you @Lukasz for your response. But above method seems to be giving error when using any parameter in the query. Like in the above example when using 'Rahul' is giving error

Comment: @arora The initial question is answered.  In order to pass arguments inside a different syntax is required [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query USING (variables)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate.html).

Comment: @arora Second you should escape `'` inside main EXECUTE IMMEDIATE `'` either by doubling it or using `\'` - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-text.html#single-quoted-string-constants